# How to align mutilple img and radio button inline?

Tags: html

I want to align img and radio button inline like this.

```
img   img   img

radio radio radio
```

I tried

```
<div><img style="vertical-align: middle"><input type="radio"></div>
```

but result is

```
radio
img
radio
img
radio
img
```

Comment: yes! I want to display like that

Comment: You should use grid-template for this functionality. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `flexbox` to do this

put the images and radios inside a div and set the div's style to `display:flex`

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="imgDiv"><img src="#" style="vertical-align: middle;"/><input type="radio"/></div>
    <div class="imgDiv"><img src="#" style="vertical-align: middle;"/><input type="radio"/></div>
    <div class="imgDiv"><img src="#" style="vertical-align: middle;"/><input type="radio"/></div>
</div>

<style>
.myDiv{
   display : flex;
}
.imgDiv{
  display: flex;
  flex direction: column
</style>
```