# CSS or HTML: put two circle divs next to another div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 circle divs, what I want to do is put them next to. I've looked at simular questions to mine but they don't provide with enough information.

Here is what I want to do:

[image: Check here]
How can I put the two circles next to the other div that illustrate in the image?

I have tried with

```
style="float:right"
```

But then it ends up at the far right which is not what I want.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: use inline display for circles or flexible display for parent. Look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276942/how-to-align-mutilple-img-and-radio-button-inline/67277115#67277115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `display:inline` which displays an element as an inline element.

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropdown" name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="circles">
  // HTML code for circles here.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dropdown, #circles{    
    display: inline;
}
```

```css
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown, #circles{    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#dropdown, #circles{    
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<select id="dropdown" name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="circles" style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for!